# Android R Automotive emulator with multidiplay supporting cluster screen and passenger screen

Tags: android, android-source, android-11, android-automotive

I have done below changes in Android R aosp (android-11.0.0_r29) to enable multi-display and test the same on emulator. But I see blank screen ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6Wci.png)) when I added another display using emulator settings, no luck even after rebooting/restarting emulator.

Change done in `platform/packages/services/Car/service/res/values/config.xml`

```
<string-array translatable="false" name="config_occupant_zones">
    <item>occupantZoneId=0,occupantType=DRIVER,seatRow=1,seatSide=driver</item>                 
    <item>occupantZoneId=1,occupantType=FRONT_PASSENGER,seatRow=2,seatSide=oppositeDriver</item>         <!--Newly added -->
</string-array>

<string-array translatable="false" name="config_occupant_display_mapping">
    <item>displayPort=0,displayType=MAIN,occupantZoneId=0</item>                        <!-- Newly added -->
    <item>displayPort=1,displayType=INSTRUMENT_CLUSTER,occupantZoneId=0</item>          <!-- Newly added -->
</string-array>
```

As per bootcamp videos, I can see emulator configured for Main, Instrument Cluster and Front Passenger as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9czSO.png).

Did I miss any other configurations?

Comment: where i found this path which you mentioned above? platform/packages/services/Car/service/res/values/config.xml

Comment: Hi @Aswin, can you share your fix if your problem got resolved?

Comment: Hi @Aswin, stuck on the same issue for Android 12, any help is deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set:
`BUILD_EMULATOR_CLUSTER_DISPLAY := true`

Comment: Can you be more specific, Which file and path ?

Answer (score 0):

There are following things needs to be adopted to have multiple screen support into Android-R(11).

*Note:* Your device folder could be different. Since I am using default AAOS emulator.

Move `config.xml` into overlay folder for example **device/generic/car/emulator/cluster/overlay/packages/services/Car/service/res/values**

Now, create `display_settings.xml` inside **device/generic/car/emulator/cluster**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<display-settings>
    <!-- Use physical port number instead of local id -->
    <config identifier="1" />
 
    <!-- Display settings for cluster -->
    <display name="port:1" forcedDensity="120" dontMoveToTop="true" />
</display-settings>
```

Add this file into product copy rule

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
    device/generic/car/emulator/cluster/display_settings.xml:vendor/etc/display_settings.xml
DEVICE_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS += \
    device/generic/car/emulator/cluster/overlay
```

Finally export the variable

```
export BUILD_EMULATOR_CLUSTER_DISPLAY=true
```

Now, build the emulator again. You would see multiple screen.

Multi display support is already integrated into Android-S by default. Only need to export the variable `BUILD_EMULATOR_CLUSTER_DISPLAY` and build emulator.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get other displays working on Android S Automotive by adding the following in aosp_car_emulator.mk:

PRODUCT_PRODUCT_PROPERTIES += 
hwservicemanager.external.displays=1,1920,720,160,0,2,1920,720,160,0

And it adds two displays. The first one is a cluster as defined in display_settings.xml

Still we need to export the env variabile in order to use the mentioned prop at compile time.

Very similar also on Android R Automotive

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me. Anything else I need to change? A guide will be really helpful pls.

Comment: Okay finally got it working. I have three displays (Main, Cluster and Additional). But the issue is the Additional display mirrors the Main display, and of course this is not what I want. Any clue what wrong I might be doing?

Comment: A display is usually a mirror of the primary until an Activity is launched on It.. I don't know if there is a way to avoid it

Comment: umm... that's strange. And it is not the case with AOSP Phone builds. The secondary displays operate independently.

Comment: It mirrors the display when VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR is set:
http://aospxref.com/android-13.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/hardware/display/DisplayManager.java#288
If you don;t want mirror then you should use VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY instead.

Comment: I think this can't be set at AOSP compile-time.. this can be set if you are creating a display at runtime