# AAOS support multiscreen and multiuser

Tags: android-source

https://source.android.com/docs/automotive/start/releases/u_udc_release

android 14 statement that AAOS has been support **Concurrent multi-user** , I want to know how to build an emulator image that support multi screen and multi user

I have refer this page
[Android R Automotive emulator with multidiplay supporting cluster screen and passenger screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66220433/android-r-automotive-emulator-with-multidiplay-supporting-cluster-screen-and-pas)
but it does't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Multi user with Multi display is a new, experimental feature in Android 14, not to be used in production environments.

To enable it, try setting the value of config_multiuserVisibleBackgroundUsers to true in frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can use sdk_car_md_(abi) to easily create multi-display setups and enable concurrent multi-user emulation.

https://android.googlesource.com/device/generic/car/+/refs/heads/main/sdk_car_md_x86_64.mk

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).